# Can we use NMOS to drive WS2812

Tags: esp32, nmos, ws2812b

My ESP32 control circuits all use NMOS for external control. I wonder if the data control of WS2812 can be driven via NMOS?
[image]

Comment: Why are you trying to re-invent the wheel? The nmos will only pull the data signal low, what will pull it high?  One ‘usual’ solution is to use something like a 74HCT244 to do the level translation and high current drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Besides the FET is on LED data output so it can't control the LEDs anyway, as there is no data input to LEDs as data input is tied to 5V.

Comment: What if ESP-PIN sends out a PWM signal, causing DATA to generate a 5V control signal (DATA)?

Comment: Keep in mind that it's serial data at roughly 800 kbits/sec, and the timing tolerances are on the order of 150 ns. It would be extremely difficult to make this work with a generic NMOS transistor and a passive pullup.